Deploying container to Azure Web App breaks SSH and deployed app not visible
I am trying to deploy a containerized HTML/js app to Azure Web App. The container works fine on my machine when using docker run.
However when Azure pulls my container from docker hub the app is not accessible. When trying the Web app URL I am greeted with the standard "Welcome to nginx" page. In addition to this the SSH option stops working, on accessing the SSH window under Developer tools in my Azure portal App Service I get one of the following:
"WAITING FOR NEW CONTAINER(S) TO START" followed by
"SSH CONN CLOSE"
Any idea what could be causing this?
Could it be my config files:
Docker file:
# Use the official Nginx image
FROM nginx:alpine

# Copy your Nginx configuration file
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

# Copy your static files to the Nginx html directory
COPY build /usr/share/nginx/html

# Expose port 8080
EXPOSE 8080

# Start Nginx
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]

nginx.conf:
server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}

Or could this be an issue related to my web app config on the Azure portal?
My Publishing model is set to "Container", Container Image is pointing at the image that runs fine when using "Docker run". Not sure what I'm missing...
I am very new to Azure and Docker so apologise if I'm being stupid.
My container has the following built app folder structure:
build/
app/
css/
fonts/
js/
images/
index.html
info.html
other .html files ...

If Possible, Share your Code or git Repository?

Sorry but unfortunately I am not comfortable sharing my code. I am happy to answer any questions. As mentioned above my app consists of HTM and JS files. I do not have an app.js or index.js, my js scripts are copied into my index.html file. I therefore do not have a "start" command.

Provide your App service Logs.

Try to change your Port to 80.

The SSH access issues might be due to the container not starting correctly.

Provide your Project Structure.

Are you deploying your app to Azure App Service Windows or Linux.

@AsleshaKantamsetti I have changed port to 80 but still have same issue, im using Linux

@AsleshaKantamsetti have added an example file structure above, my build folder contains all my html files and folders such as minimized js

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
